# How do I detect OverScroll in android RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overscroll

I have tried to overwrite onOverScrolled() but it is not triggered:

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public MyRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
        super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "overScrolled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My RecyclerView has `recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);`

Comment: how about override scrollVerticallyBy to detect scrolling to the end?

Comment: what is the purpose of onOverScrolled()

Comment: What do You want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve the following thing: every time I overscroll a recycler view up the "view overscrolled up" message is displayed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this to find **`bottom overscroll`** and **`top overscroll`**

> Find **`bottom overscroll`** and **`top overscroll`** Using LayoutManager

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this){
            @Override
            public int scrollVerticallyBy ( int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state ) {
                int scrollRange = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dx, recycler, state);
                int overScroll = dx - scrollRange;
                if (overScroll > 0) {
                    Utils.printLog("NILU_PILU :-> BOTTOM OVERSCROLL");
                } else if (overScroll < 0) {
                    Utils.printLog("NILU_PILU :-> TOP OVERSCROLL");
                }
                return scrollRange;
            }
        };
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        addDataToList();

        adapter = new DataAdapter(this, arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void addDataToList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            arrayList.add("NILU_PILU :-> " + i);
        }
    }

}
```

> Find **`bottom overscroll`**  Using `RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener()`

```
 myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dy > 0) {

                int pos = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                int numItems = myRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();

                if (pos >= numItems - 1 ) {
                    Utils.printLog("NILU_PILU :-> BOTTOM OVERSCROLL");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes, this works but gives multiple overscroll calls on one swipe up or one swipe down: http://tinypic.com/r/mrwu4k/9

Comment: @Ivan have u tried using `RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener()`

Comment: yes, tried that for bottom overscroll, did not work for me. So far I could not find ideal solution. the ones above work but not consistently. I have a fragment with horizontal CalendarView in WEEK mode and Viewpager with RecyclerView inside under thet CalendarView. I need to detect overscroll to switch between WEEK mode and MONTH mode. Your solution works fine for TOP overscroll, but when I overscroll BOTTOM to switch CalendarView to WEEK mode the whole thing sometimes blinks

Comment: here is a screen recording of what happens https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Uat6ICnQw_pttvjqP2cY21VFGcrhoGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ivan It looks like what you intent to achieve can be done with a Collapsingtoolbar instead. Place your calendar in the Collpsingtoolbar, it will manage the over scroll for you.

Comment: @Nilesh Then, how to block bottom overscroll?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution I found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2t01e0/detect_overscroll_in_recyclerview/):

Instead of a custom recyclerview, you create a custom LinearLayoutManager and just overwrite your layout managers `scrollVerticallyBy()` method and check if dx/dy minus the value returned by the super implementation is != 0. Then overscroll has occured.

```
@Override
public int scrollVerticallyBy ( int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, 
RecyclerView.State state ) {
    int scrollRange = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dx, recycler, state);
    int overscroll = dx - scrollRange;
    if (overscroll > 0) {
        // bottom overscroll
    } else if (overscroll < 0) {
        // top overscroll
    }
    return scrollRange;
}
```