# Disable overscroll effect at the bottom on RecyclerView

Tags: android

In my program, bottom over scroll effect looks bad, so I want to show overscroll effect only at the top.

[image]

This is xml file containing the recyclerview.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/day_events_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I set attribute `android:overScrollMode="never"`, both top and bottom over scroll effects  are not showing.
Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379574/how-do-i-detect-overscroll-in-android-recyclerview

Comment: @Dmitriy, But how to block it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a listener like this:

```
myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if (dy > 0) {

            int pos = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            int numItems = myRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();

            if (pos >= numItems - 1 ) {
                recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
            }else{
                 recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS); 
              }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just want to block bottom over scroll, not detecting.

Comment: Detecting bottom overscroll, you can block it using `recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);` and re-enable again when you are not in the bottom

Comment: Ah, okay. Then can you share the full code? Currently, your answer is not explained enough to be accepted.